# Unable to init/run Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-storage-emulator

Unable to init/run Azure Storage Emulator

I am trying to create an Azure Function, and running into issues at the very start.  I have VS 2017 enterprise, I created a template Azure function, and when I go to debug, it lets me know the typical (paraphrased) 'couldn't start Azure Storage Emulator, please run azurestorageemulator.exe start as admin.  I've done this with VSStudio running as admin and normal, same result.

(As an aside, when I originally started this yesterday, I was on 5.4.x.x of the emulator... I went through everything I could find including deleting/restarting the localdb instance... Then there was an interesting point where, I decided to update visual studio and all components, and after doing that and a restart, I opened the VS template project and ran debug, and it just worked, the emulator command window opened and ran and was showing all expected output, etc.  I shut down for the night, but coming back to it the next day, now I'm back to my original problem state.)

So I go to do that (from first paragraph, running storage emulator as admin), and I basically get an error probing (localdb)/MSSQLLocalDB (full error log will be at bottom):

Probing SQL Instance: '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.

The summed up error was that init should be run, though I think the issue was more one of accessing the local db in the first place... still, I tried init, with similar issues:

I have gone through the steps of deleting mssqllocaldb and the azurestorageemulator mdf and similar files, which went as expected, no issues... here are the current info details of the db:

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>sqllocaldb i
MSSQLLocalDB
v11.0

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>sqllocaldb i "MSSQLLocalDB"
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            13.1.4001.0
Shared name:
Owner:              {MyComputer'sName, replaced actual value here}\{MyUserProfile, replaced actual value}
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    3/13/2019 3:38:36 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#B161531A\tsql\query

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>
```

Here are the full outputs of the emulator start/init calls.  ANY help or thoughts would be appreciated!

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.7.0.0 command line tool
Autodetect requested. Autodetecting SQL Instance to use.
Looking for a LocalDB Installation.
Probing SQL Instance: '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.
Number of SqlErrors Reported: 1
SqlError: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.
Could not find a LocalDB Installation.
Probing SQL Instance: 'localhost\SQLExpress'.
Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
Number of SqlErrors Reported: 1
SqlError: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
No available SQL Instance was found.
One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again.
Error: The storage emulator needs to be initialized. Please run the 'init' command.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>
```

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe init
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.7.0.0 command line tool
Empty SQL Instance. Autodetecting SQL Instance to use.
Looking for a LocalDB Installation.
Probing SQL Instance: '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.
Number of SqlErrors Reported: 1
SqlError: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.
Could not find a LocalDB Installation.
Probing SQL Instance: 'localhost\SQLExpress'.
Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
Number of SqlErrors Reported: 1
SqlError: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
No available SQL Instance was found.
One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again.
Error: No available SQL Instance was found.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>
```

---

Here's the full AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config file, in case it's useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="StorageEmulatorConfig" type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.Configuration.StorageEmulatorConfigurationHandler, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller"/>
  </configSections>

  <StorageEmulatorConfig>
    <services>
      <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:10000/"/>
      <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:10001/"/>
      <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:10002/"/>
    </services>

    <!-- NOTE: These are preconfigured accounts with well known keys. The purpose of the
      authentication supported by the Storage Emulator is simply to allow you to test
      your authentication code. It has no security purpose.
      It is strongly recommended that you DO NOT use your actual storage account or key over here.
      These keys are stored unencrypted on disk and in SQL databases.
      -->
    <accounts>
      <account name="devstoreaccount1" authKey="{ActualValueRemoved}" />
    </accounts>
  </StorageEmulatorConfig>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="mscorlib" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Services" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

---

Also, here are the contents of the config file in AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\AzureStorageEmulator.5.7.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StorageEmulator xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SQLInstance />
  <PageBlobRoot>C:\Users\{I STRIPPED OUT MY USER PROFILE NAME}\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\PageBlobRoot</PageBlobRoot>
  <BlockBlobRoot>C:\Users\{I STRIPPED OUT MY USER PROFILE NAME}\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\BlockBlobRoot</BlockBlobRoot>
  <LogPath>C:\Users\{I STRIPPED OUT MY USER PROFILE NAME}\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\Logs</LogPath>
  <LoggingEnabled>false</LoggingEnabled>
</StorageEmulator>
```

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#how-the-storage-emulator-works ? 
 Have you tried using the forceCreate flag ? Have you tried to use your dedicated SQLExpress instance instead of localDb? The error it gives you is clear: the Windows principal it's trying to use to connect to localDB doesn't have access.

Comment: I've tried all of that, this seems to be outside of the typical pattern.  
I had 3 versions of localdb installed from past VS installs, I presume... I first got it working when I updated the azure SDKs, it worked briefly and I thought things were good... but then after a reboot, it went back to this issue.

I ended up deleting all of them and reinstalling localdb from the 2017 Visual Studio Installer (running a repair), and it started working again after that fix... I thought I was solid, developed for a day or two, but then I reboot, and once again, back to the same state.  *sigh*

Comment: Seems like I can temporarily fix it by re-installing localdb, but it only works until a reboot, is time consuming, and I think I lose anything stored in the db.